# Insert Into Array of object MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a25af80d2c4dd065991dccc"),
    "username" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$ptFyLKtyyrL5gMYdXS6wV.HLUA4Py5iudMJDldf5qsHFS4.9TPCyy",
    "role" : "Admin",
    "__v" : 0,
    "list" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "We",
            "arr" : [ 
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75", 
                "5a395bb0976d5304c07f7dd4"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "sandeep",
            "arr" : [ 
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add an element inside list.arr where name = 'we'
and add only if the element does not exist

how do i perform this query.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem

Comment: you can't achieve this one with single query, because this is nested document array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this nested query I solved this problem.
I'm doing it with Node JS

```
router.post('/prevList', (req, res) => {
  User.update({'_id':req.user.id, list: { $elemMatch: { name: req.body.name } } },{  $addToSet: { "list.$.arr": {$each: req.body.arr} } },function(err,data) {
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data)
  });
});
```

Here

```
req.body: {name:'we',arr:["5a395bb0976d5304c07f7dd4"]}
```

and `req.user.id` is the auth id.

Hope this helps you all too.

Answer (score 1):

if i properly understood you question,you want to match `name` field with `we` key,and update `arr` only if it exists ?, you have to use elemMatch, in other to get the right document

```
db.test.update({ list: { $elemMatch: { name: "We" , arr: { $nin: [ "valuette" ] }} } }, {  $push: { "list.$.arr": "valuette" } } );
```

the `$` in "list.$.arr" matches the specified index that matches `name` field with `we` value

update: to answer OP question

Comment: It is if the element inside the array exist

Comment: I want to push if the element does not exist inside the array

Comment: ok, check the new update, it solves your problem, `$nin` operator checks if valuette is not in the arr array, then it does the update

Answer (score 1):

Intial database structure

```
> db.collection.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a25af80d2c4dd065991dccc"),
    "username" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$ptFyLKtyyrL5gMYdXS6wV.HLUA4Py5iudMJDldf5qsHFS4.9TPCyy",
    "role" : "Admin",
    "__v" : 0,
    "list" : [
        {
            "name" : "We",
            "arr" : [
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75",
                "5a395bb0976d5304c07f7dd4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "sandeep",
            "arr" : [
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Query executed

```
> db.collection.update({ list: { $elemMatch: { name: "We" , arr: {$nin: ["55555555555555555"]} } } }, {  $push: { "list.$.arr": "55555555555555555" } } )
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

New database structure

```
> db.collection.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a25af80d2c4dd065991dccc"),
    "username" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$ptFyLKtyyrL5gMYdXS6wV.HLUA4Py5iudMJDldf5qsHFS4.9TPCyy",
    "role" : "Admin",
    "__v" : 0,
    "list" : [
        {
            "name" : "We",
            "arr" : [
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75",
                "5a395bb0976d5304c07f7dd4",
                "55555555555555555"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "sandeep",
            "arr" : [
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Again same query Executed

```
> db.collection.update({ list: { $elemMatch: { name: "We" , arr: {$nin: ["55555555555555555"]} } } }, {  $push: { "list.$.arr": "55555555555555555" } } )
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Checking the database structure again

```
> db.collection.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a25af80d2c4dd065991dccc"),
    "username" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$ptFyLKtyyrL5gMYdXS6wV.HLUA4Py5iudMJDldf5qsHFS4.9TPCyy",
    "role" : "Admin",
    "__v" : 0,
    "list" : [
        {
            "name" : "We",
            "arr" : [
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75",
                "5a395bb0976d5304c07f7dd4",
                "55555555555555555"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "sandeep",
            "arr" : [
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**No changes Found**

Comment: @SandeepRanjan ill check it again and will update the above asap

Comment: @SandeepRanjan Please check the query and notify