# How to display the content of the book

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to create an ebook using NodeJS, MongoDB and Express. So far I can just display all chapters as simple list, shown in Fig. 1. Obviously ebook should've subchapters as well, so I want to be able to click on Chapter 1 and see subchapters as shown in Fig. 2.

My questions are: how to create those subchapters? How database should looks? How to manipulate with all that data? How to display it properly?

P.S. I already saw use cases at MongoDB site, but it didn't help me.

Code fragments (ebook.js model, ebookmain.pug view, app.js route):

model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

let Schema = mongoose.Schema

//ebook schema
let ebookSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String
})

// ebook model
let Ebook = mongoose.model('Ebook', ebookSchema)

module.exports = Ebook
```

view

```
extends layout

block content
  h1.page-header #{title}
  ul.list-group
    each ebook, i in ebookpages
      li.list-group-item
        a.newsLinks(href='/ebookpages/' + ebook._id)= ebook.title
```

route

```
app.get('/ebookmain', (req, res) => 
    Ebook.find({}, (err, ebookpages) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render('ebookmain', {title: 'Ebook', ebookpages})
        }
    }))
```

Fig. 1.

[image]

Fig. 2.

[image]

**Edited.**

How to add/edit subchapters?

What to do when I have subchapters of subchapter?

Code fragment of adding new chapters (routes/ebookpages.js):

```
// add route
router.get('/add', (req, res) =>
    res.render('add_ebook', {title: 'Add content'}))
// add submit post route
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    let ebook = new Ebook()
    ebook.title = req.body.title
    ebook.body = req.body.body
    ebook.save(err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        } else {
            res.redirect('/ebookmain')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: It's a tree; there are many ways this can be implemented, including NPM packages that do a lot of the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let ebookSchema = new Schema({
        title: String,
        body: String,
        subChapters:[{
          name: String,
          content: String,
        }]
    });
```

Let say you have something like this in you collection

```
    [{
       _id: '1',
       title: 'book 1',
       body: '.....',
       subChapters[]
    },{
      _id: '2'
      title: book 2'
      body: '....',
      subChapters: [{ 
                     name: 'sub-1',
                     content: '....'}]

}]
```

//app.js

```
const EB = require('./ebook.js');

//Let's say you need to add something to the array i.e subChapters.

 var obj = { name: 'sub1', content:'......'};

 EB.update({_id: '1'},{ $push: { subChapters: obj } }, function(err, info){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(info);
});
```

This was when you are only adding one subchapter at a time.

Let's say you want to add more than one subChapters then you will be using `$each` docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Use `$pull` to delete from array docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

To insert something at a particular location check my this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47966974/8380606

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your schema and add an array of objects that will have the details and content of your sub-chapters

```
//ebook.js 
let ebookSchema = new Schema({
        title: String,
        body: String,
        subChapters:[{
          name: String,
          content: String,
        }]
    });

let Ebook = mongoose.model('Ebook', ebookSchema)

module.exports = Ebook
```

route

```
//app.js

app.get('/ebookmain', (req, res) => 
    Ebook.find({}, (err, ebookpages) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render('ebookmain', {title: 'Ebook', ebookpages})
        }
    }));
```

This is your views file. to get the drop-down use css

```
//- ebookmain.pug
extends layout

block content
  h1.page-header #{title}
  ul.list-group
    each ebook, i in ebookpages
      li.list-group-item
        a.newsLinks(href='/ebookpages/' + ebook._id)= ebook.title
         if ebookpages.subChapters.length
          ul
           each subChap in ebookpages.subChapters
            li.list-group-item
              a.newSubChp(href='/ebookpages/'+ebook._id+'/'+subChap.name) = subChap.name
```

Then you just need to get the data from the array. :) Hope this helps

Comment: In this app I can add/edit chapters, so I wonder how to implement this features to subchapters as well? Check my new code fragment.

Comment: What to do when I have subchapters of subchapter?

Comment: Your can do operation on the subchapters array.

Comment: Code fragment above (see Edited).

Comment: Can you provide example of operation on the subchapters array?

Comment: @BlackB0ne If my answer's help pls accept it. :) thanks .. any more help ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163882/discussion-between-sandeep-ranjan-and-blackb0ne).

Answer (score 0):

Your Schema Structure would be look like this:

```
let ebookSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    subchpaters:[{
      name: String,
      content: String,
    }]
})



 Ebook.find({title:'example'}, (err, ebookpages) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else if(ebookpages) {
            Ebook.find({"subchpaters.name","subchpaters.content"}, (err, doc) => {
             if(err) {
               console.log("error",err);
             } else {
               console.log("doc",doc);
             }
        }
```

Comment: you can make serveral other chnages regarding your need this could be one example